# Scroll in MS Access is Too Fast

Tags: ms-access, ms-office

I want to use my touch pad to scroll in Microsoft Access.  Problem is when I do the smallest vertical scroll gesture that I can, it moves the records 15+ spaces up or down the page (usually more). It also does the same thing with my mouse (when using the wheel). I have a couple hundred thousand records so maybe that has something to do with it. It has left me no choice but to use the keyboard at this moment. My Microsoft mouse settings (which I assume control the touch pad as well) are only set to scroll 5 lines at a time. So what is the deal?

It would be greatly appreciated if someone has an answer to this problem.

Nick

Answer (score 1):

Touchpad settings are separate from Mouse settings but, depending on your computer manufacturer, you might need to update your mouse driver so give you the touchpad options UI.  For example, my HP Laptop did not show touchpad options when I had a fresh install of Windows, until I updated the drivers.  (Either through the [HP website](https://support.hp.com/ca-en/drivers), or with the `Update Driver` button shown below; I can't remember which since I did them both.)  After the update, the *Synaptics ClickPad* Tab showed up in Mouse Settings, as shown below.

[image]

---

Depending on where you are having this issue, there be another solution.  If the symptoms of your issue are:

> In Form View in Microsoft Office Access 2007 or in Microsoft Access
>   2010, when you try to use the mouse wheel to move through records in a
>   form, nothing happens. However, you can use the mouse wheel to move
>   records up and down when you switch the form to Datasheet View

Then your solution is in [Microsoft Support Article 2458709](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2458709/you-cannot-use-the-mouse-wheel-to-scroll-through-records-in-an-access).